# Representation of an entangled state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I am reading the [EPR paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.47.777). In the second section, they introduce a quantum wavefunction $\Psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)$

> Let $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, \cdots$ be the eigenvalues of some physical quantity $A$ pertaining to system I and $u_{1}\left(x_{1}\right), \quad u_{2}\left(x_{1}\right), \quad u_{3}\left(x_{1}\right), \cdots$ the corresponding eigenfunctions, where $x_{1}$ stands for the variables used to describe the first system. Then $\Psi$, considered as a function of $x_{1}$, can be expressed as
> $$
> \Psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \psi_{n}\left(x_{2}\right) u_{n}\left(x_{1}\right), \quad\quad\quad (7)
> $$
> where $x_{2}$ stands for the variables used to describe the second system. Here $\psi_{n}\left(x_{2}\right)$ are to be regarded merely as the coefficients of the expansion of $\Psi$ into a series of orthogonal functions $u_{n}\left(x_{1}\right)$.

It is argued that the same wavefunction is represented in another way w.r.t some other basis

> If, instead of this, we had chosen another quantity, say $B$, having the eigenvalues $b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3}, \cdots$ and eigenfunctions $v_{1}\left(x_{1}\right), v_{2}\left(x_{1}\right), v_{3}\left(x_{1}\right), \cdots$ we should have obtained, instead of Eq. (7), the expansion
> $$
> \Psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=\sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \varphi_{s}\left(x_{2}\right) v_{s}\left(x_{1}\right), \qquad\qquad (8)
> $$
> where $\varphi_{s}$ 's are the new coefficients. If now the quantity $B$ is measured and is found to have the value $b_{r}$, we conclude that after the measurement the first system is left in the state given by $v_{r}\left(x_{1}\right)$ and the second system is left in the state given by $\varphi_{r}\left(x_{2}\right)$.

From the discussion it seems like the equation (7) and (8) are the expansion of the state in two different bases. But they speak of two 'systems' not two bases. When we say two systems, we take them as two particles or something like that. But how can it be two systems when it is only the expansion of a state in another basis.

I wonder how can I represent the equation (7) or (8) in Dirac notation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion stems from what is the system and what is the state.  The system is the measurement apparatus, which sometimes leaves the state of the particles  unchanged if it happens to be in an eigenstate of the apparatus.  If it’s not in an eigenstate of the apparatus then the state will be changed.  This is the crux of the issue in EPR, you measure , let’s say, X on particle 1 and then P on particle 2.  But since X and P don’t commute, have you actually simulaneously measured X and P?

Comment: was the idea of entanglement proposed as a counter argument? or was it there already? If entanglement was already known then how can Einstein argue like that, since the system 1 would have instantaneously got affected(idk how!) with the measurement on the system 2